# Is there a way to scrape data from a PDF into a structured JSON format?

Tags: python, r, json, pdf, uipath

I am trying extract data from PDF. The data to be extracted in a structured way. For example document id and its corresponding value. we have to extract a set of key-value pairs as a json format and stored in db. Is there a way to accomplish this task?

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/python-for-pdf-ef0fac2808b0

Comment: Please share the sample data as extracting data from a pdf requires to understand structure of the data to be extracted.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using UIPath you need to install 2 packages:

1.Uipath PDF Activities - to read the pdf

2.UiPath Web Activities - here you can find DeserializeJSON activity (or DeserializeJSON array )

***Personally I would extract the data and save it in xlsx file